# Copy attributes from element in xsl

Tags: xslt, soap, xslt-1.0, ibm-datapower

I have a soap request in context variable, that is a response too:

```
<soap:Envelope>
  <xsl:copy-of select="dp:variable('var://context/Requestdata/STRequest')"/>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now, I want that the response will be one new element, with attributes of a specific element from the context variable:

```
<soap:Envelope>
  <NewElement att1="xxx" att2="yyy" att3="zzz"/>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the result of the first snippet, what is the name of the element whose attributes you want to copy? Anyway, I supposed you want e.g. `<NewElement><xsl:copy-of select="dp:variable('var://context/Requestdata/STRequest')//foo/@*"/></NewElement>` where `foo` would be the name of the element.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works!! How can I add more attributes to NewElement attributes that copied?